# Running version specific code in python gives me error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I am new to the Python language. I saw a StackOverflow question on how to run a version specific code in a python script. I have written the following code :

```
import sys

mylist = []
mylist.append(1)
mylist.append(2)
mylist.append(3)

str=""

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    print("version 2\n")
    for x in mylist:
        str += "{}".format(x)
    print(str)
else:
    print("version 3 or above\n")
    for x in mylist:
        print(x, end='')
    print()
```

But this code gives me an error as follows -

> File "test.py", line 18
>       print(x, end='')
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

If I run this code in Python2 it gives an error in the else part. Why is it entering the else block?

Comment: The error means it's not valid *syntax*; this is a failure when Python tries to *parse* the code not when it's executed. For syntax changes, use [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) imports (`print_function`, in this case).

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes I know, but why is it entering the else block even though I am using Python2.x?

Comment: It's **not** entering the `else` block; again, this is at *parsing* time, not execution. Python has to parse the whole script before it can run it.

Comment: So, there's no way to run version specific code in Python? Like if I want to use print with 'end=' with Python2.x set up as in if else block?

Comment: Could you please read the whole of my first comment? As a side note: the method you're using works fine for version-specific functionality *as long as it's syntactically valid* in all versions.

Comment: ok, got it, will need to use future and print_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SyntaxError` is happening before your code runs, python will check all lines of the codes and looking for syntax issues based on the version of python interpreter which is not ok in python2.x, that is why you get that error(Not entering the block, because your code does not start yet) solution is using `__future__` and import `print_function`.

Answer (score 0):

Error is at compile time, not at the time of execution of program.
Compiler will try to compile both the `if..else` blocks in python 2.
Python2's compiler doesn't support the given `print(x, end='')` syntax.